# Equally spaced points on a circle

Tags: geometry

This is a variation on a question that's been asked a few times, but I'm currently brain fogged enough that I apparently can't see the forest for the trees.

Given a circle with radius r, I need to determine how many points I can put on the circle that are at least 2 (linear, not measured along the arc) units apart from each other. I'm working in radians, if that matters at all.

[image]

(Edit, the '2' in the diagram above should be '$\ge$2')

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume (without any real basis except a certain amount of experience) that an optimal solution is one that starts with a point at $(r, 0)$, follows with another point whose distance from that is *exactly* 2, and so on, until you go "all the way around the circle."

To make life easier for myself, I'm going to replace the question with "On a *unit* circle, how many points with distance $h = \frac{2}{r}$ can I fit?" (That's the original question, scaled down by a factor of $r$ in all directions.)

Well, you need a point
$$
P = (\sin t, \cos t)
$$
with the property that 
$$
(1 - \sin t, \cos t)
$$
has length $h$, so 
\begin{align}
h^2 &= 1 - 2\sin t + \sin^2 t + \cos^2 t \\
h^2 &= 1 - 2\sin t + 1 \\
h^2 &=2 - 2\sin t \\
h^2 &=2 - 2\sin t \\
2-h^2 &= 2 \sin t \\
1-\frac{h^2}{2} &=  \sin t 
\end{align}

so $t = \arcsin \left( 1 - \frac{h^2}{2} \right)$.

You're now going to mark off points at angles $0, t, 2t, 3t, \ldots$ until you've gone almost all the way around the circle. There will be 
two cases:

1. $n = \frac{2\pi}{t}$ is an integer. In this case, the $n$ angles $0, t, 2t, \ldots, (n-1)t$ determine the points you desire.
2. $n$ is not an integer. In that case, the $n-1$ angles $0, t, 2t, \ldots (n-2)t$ determine the points you desire.

Converting back to your notation:

1. Let $t = \arcsin(1 - \frac{2}{r^2})$.
2. Compute $n = \frac{2\pi}{t}$.
3. If $n$ is an integer, then you can fit $n$ points with all pariwise distances at least $2$.
4. Otherwise, you can fit $\lfloor n \rfloor$ such points. (Note: $\lfloor n \rfloor$ denotes the largest integer less than or equal to $n$, i.e., the result of "rounding $n$ down".)

Note that if $r < 1$, then in step 1 you're computing the arcsine of a number less than $-1$, which is impossible. This corresponds to the notion that on a circle smaller than the unit circle, you cannot find even two points whose distance is at least $2$.

Comment: good, but if $n$ is not integer, you cant have $n-1$, yet $floor(n)$. And the scale factor is $r$ not $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Two points on the circle that *are* 2 units apart form a line segment that subtends an angle of $2\sin^{-1}\frac1r$ radians at the centre (bisecting the angle yields two right-angled triangles with opposite 1 and hypotenuse $r$). Therefore the number of points that can be put in is $$\left\lfloor\frac{2\pi}{2\sin^{-1}\frac1r}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac\pi{\sin^{-1}\frac1r}\right\rfloor$$
where the floor function is used to return a whole number.

Comment: Clear and effective !